# D3 show linear color range in rect

Tags: d3.js, scale

This may be a silly question but I can't seem to figure it out - is there a way in D3 to fill a rectangle based on a linear color scale? That is, I have a linear scale from white to green so I want to display a "legend" which is basically a rectangle with color transitioning from white to green. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421) is an example.

Comment: yes a gradient, thanks! @Lars if you could place your link in an answer I will mark it as answer  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an [SVG gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp). [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421) is an example in D3.